# ¿Como obtengo la informacion de un input con beautifullsoup(PYTHON)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Necesito hacer scraping a un sitio web, ya inicia sesion y realiza una busqueda pero la informacion sale de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y su  codigo html es:

```
<div class="controls">
<input id="sumaAsegurada_formatted" name="sumaAsegurada_formatted" size="17" type="tel" class="input-large populateByInsp currency " maxlength="17" data-rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Este valor puede ser incrementado o disminuido en un 10%" tabindex="19">
</div>
```

Ya con esa solucion haria los demas. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

puedes sacarlo con el nombre del input, con la clase o con un id

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#boton01").click(function () {
    //saco el valor accediendo a un input de tipo text y name = nombre
    alert($('input:text[name=nombre]').val());
    //saco el valor accediendo al id del input = nombre
    alert($("#nombre").val());
    //saco el valor accediendo al class del input = nombre   
    alert($(".nombre").val());
    });
});
</script>
```

los botones:

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="nombre" value="">
<input type="button" name="boton01" id="boton01" value="Sacar el valor del input text">
```

Comment: no se si me di a entender pero es co python